# Which of these queries is preferable?

Tags: sql

I've written the same query as a subquery and a self-join.

Is there any obvious argument for one over the other here?

**SUBQUERY:**

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name
FROM products
WHERE vend_id = (SELECT vend_id
FROM products
WHERE prod_id = ‘DTNTR’);
```

**SELF-JOIN:**

```
SELECT p1.prod_id, p1.prod_name
FROM products p1, products p2
WHERE p1.vend_id = p2.vend_id
AND p2.prod_id = ‘DTNTR’;
```

Comment: Well, for starters, they'll return different results if there's more than one vend_id for a given product, I think. I guess you probably meant to use "IN", not "=", in the subquery. I may be wrong, though, I've only just got to my first coffee of the day.

Comment: Please add (as tag) your database engine. The best way of writing your query could depend on db engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=24593) has some figures on execution times. The poster states:

> The first query shows 49.2% of the batch while the second shows 50.8%, leading
>   one to think that the subquery is marginally faster.
>
> Now, I started up Profiler and ran both queries. The first query required
>   over 92,000 reads to execute, but the one with the join required only 2300,
>   leading me to believe that the inner join is significantly faster.

There are conflicting responses though:

> My rule of thumb: only use JOIN's if you need to output a column from the
>   table you are join'ing to; otherwise, use sub-queries.

and this:

> Joining should always be faster - theoretically and realistically. Subqueries
>   - particularly correlated - can be very difficult to optimise. If you think
>   about it you will see why - technically, the subquery could be executed once
>   for each row of the outer query - blech!

I also agree with Madhivanan, if the sub query returns anything but one value your main query will fail, so use `IN` instead.

Answer (score 3):

First query may throw error if the subquery returns more than a value

Second query is not as per ANSI

So better use ANSI style join

```
SELECT p1.prod_id, p1.prod_name 
FROM products as p1 inner join products as p2 
on p1.vend_id = p2.vend_id 
WHERE p2.prod_id = ‘DTNTR’;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any of the columns from the JOINed table, then using a subselect is generally preferable, although this is dependent on RDBMs type. An IN clause should be used instead:

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name
FROM products
WHERE vend_id IN (SELECT vend_id
   FROM products
   WHERE prod_id = ‘DTNTR’);
```